# Is there any way we can change an attribute value in DOM and load page again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, google-chrome-extension

I am new to javascript and webtechnology. I have a requirement, where I have to change the lang attribute of

```
<html lang="en-US">
```

in webpage numbers of time, and then reload the page. I have designed an chrome-extension that changes lang attribute of current tab page, it is working well, but it doesn't fetches the correct Resource files as per the locale changed. It only changes lang of page in cache.

I want to know, is there any way I can basically load the page with different lang code without actually changing the source code manually ?

1. Can we pass a javascript like document.documentElement.lang="ab-CD" as webRequest and then load the page

Please help..

Comment: Use session or cookie to store lang value and fetch data accordingly

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do this entirely client-side. You have to do something to tell the *server* what language to use, and then the server has to send back the HTML page with the appropriate content.

One thing you can do (or rather, the browser can do) to tell the server what language to send back is to send the `Accept-Language` header in the HTTP request for the resource, identifying the desired language. But unless you're doing an ajax request, you can't set that header from client-side code, the browser sets it.

If you want to let the user decide the language, the simplest thing is probably to have different paths for different languages, or a query string parameter. Your server-side code would use the query-string parameter or, if none, the `Accept-Language` header.